# Burninate the stop tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Burninate [stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stop). What are you stopping and how? That's a lot more important than that *something* is stopping. Doesn't help categorizing, and as we can see by the police at every stop sign, nobody is a stop expert.

Comment: Stop the Burninate tag! Wait, no...

Comment: And the answer to your question is, according to the list of questions on that tag: Anything, everything, and nothing!

Comment: +1. It's a meta-tag.

Comment: Agreed. Most of tag uses are as a verb to add more information to what they are doing, like "stop the animation in jquery".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so this actually *is* a valid tag for jQuery animation questions. Unfortunately, those made up only about 20% of the questions it was used for.

So, done.

[image: Burned]